# Syntax error using => in IE

Tags: javascript

I have the following line of javascript code

```
var res = Object.keys(packages).filter(e => packages[e] === true)
```

The above works well in all the other browser apart from IE. IE complains about Syntax erro at `=>` can someone tell me how to get around this in IE

Comment: `.filter(function(e){ return packages[e]; })`

Comment: which version of IE

Comment: Unsupported syntax in IE - use a regular anonymous function: `.filter(function(e) {`

Comment: @SaggingRufus IE 11

Comment: @SaggingRufus — Every version of IE

Answer (score 5):

IE must not support arrow-functions. Just use the old `function` keyword.

```
.filter(function(e){ return packages[e] === true })
```

Side note, but you could also probably write this as:

```
.filter(function(e){ return packages[e] })
```

Unless `packages[e]` *must* actually be exactly equal to `true` and not just truthy.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: The code example is wrong

Comment: @FedericoGalassi Which part? I freehanded it on my phone, so I may have introduced a syntax problem.

Comment: @FedericoGalassi Whoops, I forgot the `return`s. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support the fat arrow notation (Edge does). See http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/. You need the older function notation:

```
var res = Object.keys(packages).filter(function(e) { return packages[e] === true })
```

Answer (score 1):

[CanIUse: Arrow function](https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow) You cannot use it in IE;

```
var res = Object.keys(packages).filter(function(e) = {return packages[e] === true})
```