# Load all images when intersection observer is not supported

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I'm using intersection observer for late loading images.
How can I load all images in browsers that don't support intersection observer?

My script=

```
const imob = new IntersectionObserver((entries, self) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            llo(entry.target);
            self.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
    });
});
document.querySelectorAll('.lzyp').forEach((pcu) => {
    imob.observe(pcu);
});

const llo = (pcu) => {
    const img = pcu.querySelector('img');
    const sce = pcu.querySelectorAll('source');

    sce.forEach((sue) => {
        sue.srcset = sue.dataset.srcset;
        sue.removeAttribute('data-srcset');
    });
    img.src = img.dataset.src;
    img.removeAttribute('data-src');
}
```

Comment: you can simply use load event for all your images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Maybe a [polyfill for IntersectionObserver](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/main/polyfill)?
2. Adding fallback code if IntersectionObserver is not supported.

```js
if (!('IntersectionObserver' in window) ||
    !('IntersectionObserverEntry' in window) ||
    !('intersectionRatio' in window.IntersectionObserverEntry.prototype) ||
    !('isIntersecting' in window.IntersectionObserverEntry.prototype)
) {
    // load all images here
    document.querySelectorAll('.lzyp').forEach( llo );
}
```

Resolve Arrow function is not supported in IE:

```js
// change from this
document.querySelectorAll('.lzyp').forEach((pcu) => {
    imob.observe(pcu);
});

// to this
document.querySelectorAll('.lzyp').forEach( function(pcu) {
    imob.observe(pcu);
});
```

put together:

```js
function llo(pcu) {
    const img = pcu.querySelector('img');
    const sce = pcu.querySelectorAll('source');

    sce.forEach((sue) => {
        sue.srcset = sue.dataset.srcset;
        sue.removeAttribute('data-srcset');
    });
    img.src = img.dataset.src;
    img.removeAttribute('data-src');
}

// IntersectionObserver is not supported
if (!('IntersectionObserver' in window) ||
    !('IntersectionObserverEntry' in window) ||
    !('intersectionRatio' in window.IntersectionObserverEntry.prototype) ||
    !('isIntersecting' in window.IntersectionObserverEntry.prototype)
) {
    // load all images here
    document.querySelectorAll('.lzyp').forEach( llo );
} else {
    const imob = new IntersectionObserver( function(entries, self) {
        entries.forEach( function(entry) {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                llo(entry.target);
                self.unobserve(entry.target);
            }
        });
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.lzyp').forEach(function(pcu) {
        imob.observe(pcu);
    });
}
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Comment: Any errors? Try add a `console.log(1)` inside the if statement to check if the condition is truthy, that is, browser doesn't support `IntersectionObserver`

Comment: Gives syntax error,  point of error   ( => ) line (1,58)

Comment: Is it possible for you to put your code on codesandbox or something for me to debug?

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437497/syntax-error-using-in-ie)  here it is said that ie does not support arrow functions, how can we solve this

Comment: OK, I get it. The error is from your code. I thought error is from the solutions that I provide. So you need to change every arrow function in your code to normal function, you can find an example in my updated answer.

Comment: it didn't work,  'IntersectionObserver' is undefined , console error

Comment: Well, That's because you didn't put IntersectionObserver in the `else statement`, checkout my updated answer